# cannot resolve symbol 'SpringRunner' for java Spring junit

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write a junit test for my first java project using Spring framework. I have searched online how to include the dependency in order to use it but keep encountering this warning:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringRunner'

in intelliJ IDEA. So what is missing? 
Here is my dependency file for gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-    plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile("org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.3.RELEASE")
    compile('com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.18')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

Comment: Please, can you add your test class?

Comment: I thnk your problem is the spaces in `spring-boot-gradle-    plugin` (see line 6). Try replacing it with `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;`